# Always serve unversioned files raw?

Tags: fossil

I'm serving unversioned files via fossil's `uv` function. Now, this works fine for files without file extension and for archives. But I need to serve a .txt file. The problem now is that it gets delivered as a HTML page including the fossil web layout around it.

Is there a way to tell fossil to not do that, and instead deliver it as a raw .txt file?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a `mimetype` parameter on the URL. For example, `mimetype=application/octet-stream` will cause it to be offered as download.

For example, instead of https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/uv/download.html, you’d put  https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/uv/download.html?mimetype=application/octet-stream.

Fossil reacts to [the following mimetypes](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/artifact?udc=1&name=b40e2b92dafe8597&ln=695-728) by putting headers around them:

- text/x-fossil-wiki
- text/x-markdown
- text/html
- text/plain

Unfortunately, all other mimetypes appear to lead to the browser downloading the unversioned file instead of displaying it.

If that's a problem, you could try a mimetype of `text` with no suffix.

Otherwise, you can post on Fossil's [support forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum). Either as a question or as a feature request. :-)